# pgfplot get y value of path from x value (for pins/coordinates)

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I am plotting two functions (for payments)

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,fillbetween}

\def\pOne{200}
\def\endYear{25}
\def\pTwo{150}
\def\inflation{6}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\multiplier{1+(\inflation/100)}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick distance=5,
    minor x tick num=4
  ]
    \addplot[name path=payment1,green,domain=0:35,samples=100,]
      gnuplot [id=payment1] {x<=\endYear? \pOne: 0.0}; %  can't seem to sneak a `pin=` in anywhere here
    \addplot[name path=payment2,smooth,black,domain=0:35,]
      gnuplot [id=payment2] {\pTwo*\multiplier**x};
    \fill [name intersections={ of=payment1 and payment2, by={E} }] (E) circle (1pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: my result]

I would like to be able to mark the graph up by specifying x-coordinates and path (relying on the plots to find the appropriate y-values).

For example, I would like to be able to add vertical lines between the two functions at each multiple of five `foreach \x in {0,5,...,35}` and mark the difference between them like this:

[image: example of what I'd like to achieve]

But I can't really figure out how to interact with the paths appropriately.